# ColdFusion EntityLoad Filter

Tags: orm, syntax, coldfusion

How would I in ColdFusion add <= in my Filter Criteria. I was trying this

`EntityLoad("Entity",{someProperty <= value});`

but with no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use HQL http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSf0ed2a6d7fb07688310730d81223d0356fc-7ffe.html

```
resultArray = ormExecuteQuery("from Entity where someProperty <= ?", [value])
```

Comment: Ah okay :) I thought there was a way with just entityLoad. Thanks!